# How to insert NULL/empty string in encrypted column - Always Encrypted

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

I have encrypted existing data using the SQL Server 2016 always encrypt method, one of column we have  is NULLABLE   but while insert from screen its not accepting either NULL or empty String. how to make it work if encrypted column is not mandatory on screen?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Also what do you mean when you say insert from screen?

Comment: Suppose i have SSN column in my table and its encrypted column. using my .net code(Ado.net) i am passing SSN as parameter to procedure to insert into table. its working fine if i have some value in it but if its NULL or empty then its showing error.

Comment: string _ssn =""  insert into table1 (ssn) values(_ssn)  error  -  'Operand type clash: nvarchar(4000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Database') is incompatible with nvarchar(9) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = Database')'

Comment: I have provided a sample below on how to pass parameters to SP when using always encrypted. If you share your code, schema and stored procedure, I can help point out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are seeing is incorrect, please ensure that you are passing the parameter correctly. Here is some sample code on how to do so.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SO](
    [ssn] [nvarchar](9) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertSP @ssn nvarchar(9)
AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SO] ([SSN]) VALUES (@SSN);
GO
```

**C# code:**

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder strbldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        strbldr.DataSource = ".";
        strbldr.InitialCatalog = @"exptdb";
        strbldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        strbldr.ColumnEncryptionSetting = SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting.Enabled;

        string ssn = "";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strbldr.ConnectionString))
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand()) {

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = @"dbo.insertSP";

            SqlParameter paramSSN = command.CreateParameter();
            paramSSN.ParameterName = "@ssn";
            paramSSN.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            paramSSN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramSSN.Value = ssn;
            paramSSN.Size = 9;
            command.Parameters.Add(paramSSN);

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

**Note**, that in the scenario mentioned above, if

```
string ssn = "";
```

then the query succeeds, however if

```
string ssn = null;
```

you should see a failure on execution

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'insertSP' expects
>   parameter '@ssn', which was not supplied.

This failure will occur even when ssn column is plaintext

You can insert null value in the encrypted column as follows, since null values are not encrypted:

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strbldr.ConnectionString))
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand()) {

            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[SO] ([SSN]) VALUES (null)";

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: This is not a parameter query which violates security standards. Do you have a better suggesstion ?